# Parse::RecDescent - getting information from it

Tags: perl, parse-recdescent

I'm working with the [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse::RecDescent) parser in Perl, and I seem to have the most terrible time getting information from it. The information readily available online does not seem to have non-trivial examples.

Here is the code:

```
event_function: object_list ':' event_list ';'
        <defer:
        {       #item is a special character with Parse::Recdescent.
            print Dumper($item{object_list});
            $return = $item[1];
        }
        >
        | object_list ':' ';'
        <defer:
        { 
            print Dumper($item{object_list});
            $return = $item[1];
        }
        >
```

Here is the output

```
PS W:\developers\paulnathan\rd_dir> perl parser.pl testfile
$VAR1 = 4;
$VAR1 = 8;
PS W:\developers\paulnathan\rd_dir>
```

The input file parses correctly.

```
stuff, stuff2: pre-operation event = {foo1, foo2};
```

It *should* be outputting a hash keyed by "stuff", "stuff2".

Thoughts?

edit:

```
object_list : 
        object ',' object_list
        <defer:
        {

            my $retval = ();
            $retval = ::merge_hash_refs($item[1], $item[3]);

            $return = $retval;
        }
        >
        | object
        <defer:
        { 
            #print Dumper($item{object});
            $return = $item{object};
        }
        >       

    object : 
        '/' /[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_]*/ '/' '...'
            <defer:
            {
                $::objects->{$item[2]} = "stuff";
                $return = $::objects;
            }
            >
        |  /[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_]*/
            <defer:
            { 
                $::objects->{$item[1]} = "stuff";
                $return = $::objects;
            }
            >
```

edit2:
Merge_hash_refs, just in case. :-)

```
#takes two hash references.
sub merge_hash_refs {
    my($ref1, $ref2) = @_;
    my $retref = ();
    while( my ($k, $v) = each %$ref1 ) {
        $retref->{$k} = $v;
    }
    while( my ($k, $v) = each %$ref2 ) {
        $retref->{$k} = $v;
    }

    return $retref;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the object_list and event_list rules?

Comment: Event_list is not returning anything; object_list added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a `use strict` to your script you'll get the fatal error *Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at [the call to `merge_hash_refs`]*. It appears that the closures created by the `<defer>` directives are causing the contents of `@item` to be the ones when the production matched instead of the hashrefs eventually returned by the subrules. Removing the `<defer>` directives gives me this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'stuff2' => 'stuff',
          'stuff' => 'stuff'
        };
```

Of course, this has the side effect that $::object is updated by successful `object` productions even if the higher level rules fail (including backtracking). I'd write it this way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parse::RecDescent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new(<<'EOT');
event_function: object_list ':' event_list(?) ';'
    {
        $return = $item[1];
    }

object_list : <leftop: object ',' object>
    {
        $return = { map { %$_ } @{$item[1]} };
    }

object : 
    '/' /[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_]*/ '/' '...'
        {
            $return = { $item[2] => 'stuff' };
        }
    |  /[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_]*/
        { 
            $return = { $item[1] => 'stuff' };
        }

# stub, don't know what this should be
event_list : /[^;]+/

EOT

my %object;

while (<DATA>) {
    my $x = $parser->event_function($_);

    next unless $x;

    # merge objects into master list
    while (my ($k, $v) = each %$x) {
        $object{$k} = $v;
    }
}

print Dumper \%object;

__DATA__
stuff, stuff2: pre-operation event = {foo1, foo2};
stuff3, stuff4: ;
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'stuff2' => 'stuff',
          'stuff3' => 'stuff',
          'stuff' => 'stuff',
          'stuff4' => 'stuff'
        };
```

Comment: That makes a kind of evil sense. Sigh. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an answer to your question, but when you start an each() loop through a hash, if each() had previously been used on the hash it just starts from wherever the iterator was pointing.  To be safe, put a void-context keys() (e.g. keys(%$ref1);) before the while loop to reset the iterator.  Older versions of Data::Dumper had a cute little bug of leaving the iterator pointing just after the last element sometimes, making the hash appear to be empty to an unsafe while(...each...) loop :)

Comment: That wasn't the answer, but I'm glad you told me. :-)